# AWS Serverless VPC Subnet Creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

If I create VPC and Subnets using my serverless.yml file and I deploy it later again does the VPC get created again ? Or only incremental changes are pushed.

Answer (score 0):

Serverless.yml file compiles down to valid CloudFormation. It will only create a new VPC if it's being created for the first time. If some part of its configuration are changed in the file, it'll update the existing one. If nothing is changed, it won't touch VPC at all. When you deploy your CloudFormation template, the service looks for differences between current deployed stack and the stack that you described in your file. That's how it figures out, what actions to perform.

So, the answer is **no**. It won't duplicate your AWS resources on subsequent deployments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about the serverless framework, but if it's properly based on CloudFormation as the other answer suggests, then this is what is true about CloudFormation:

It depends on whether you change a property of the underlying resource that requires replacement. For `VPC`, see list of properties here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpc.html

You can see that updates to `CidrBlock` require replacement -- this means a new VPC will be created and then the old one will be deleted.

For `Subnet` see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-subnet.html -- there's `CidrBlock`, `AvailabilityZone` and `VpcId` which require replacement. Obviously, if the VPC is recreated so will be the subnet.

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy the VPC using Serverless, then only changes will be deployed and configured on every subsequent 'sls deploy'. You're able to change settings and your changes will be reflected on the same VPC resources. You can make Serverless VPC creation a lot easier with the "serverless-vpc-plugin".

https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-vpc-plugin

You can see a full working serverless template here:

https://carova.io/snippets/serverless-aws-vpc-create-custom-vpc-with-template